# Spring JPA connect two tables with Oher column

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables People And Car.

```
@Entity
public class People {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private  String address;
    //private Integer OtherID;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Car> carList;  
}

@Entity
public class Car {

    @Id
    private Long id;
 //private Integer OtherID;
    private String name;
}
```

How can I connect this two tables with OtherID?? In exiting People and Car table I have OtherId column and I must use it.

Thank you for help me

Comment: Are you asking for 2 separate joins between People and Car, or just 1 join where it is linked by the OtherID?

Comment: Only 1 join linked by the OtherID